# php preg_match_all not specific number

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all

I want to exclude a specific number like 4800 from a string of numbers like 569048004801.
I'm using php for this and the method preg_match_all some pattern's examples I have tried :

```
/([^4])([^8])([^0])([^0])/i
/([^4800])/i
```

Comment: `[^4800]` is the same as `[^480]` and means "in any particular single spot, do not allow a 4, 8, or 0. `/i` is pointless as well. there's no such thing as an upper case number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
/([^4])([^8])([^0])([^0])/i
```

This actually says, *a sequence of four characters that is not "4800"*.  Close.

```
/([^4800])/i
```

This actually says, *a single character that is not '4', '8', or '0'*.

Assuming you mean to capture a number that doesn't contain "4800" in it, I think you might want

```
/(?!\d*4800)\d+/i
```

This says, *check first that we're not looking at a string of numbers with "4800" somewhere, and provided this is the case, capture the string of numbers*.  It's called a "negative lookahead assertion".

Answer (score 3):

If you just want to see if a string contain 4800, you don't need regular expressions :

```
<?php

$string = '569048004801';

if(strpos($string,'4800') === false){
  echo '4800 was not found in the string';
}
else{
  echo '4800 was found in the string'; 
}
```

More information about strpos in the [documentation here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php)

Answer (score 2):

If you mean you simply want to remove `4800` from a string, this is easier with a `str_replace`:

```
$str = '569048004801';
$str = str_replace('4800', '', $str);
```

On the other hand, if you mean you want to know if a particular string of digits contains `4800`, this will test that for you:

```
$str = '569048004801';

if (preg_match_all('/4800/', $str) > 0) {
    echo 'String contains 4800.';
} else {
    echo 'String does not contain 4800.';
}
```